# How to get values from PrimeFaces multiple autocomplete with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, primefaces

I have a Primefaces multiple autocomplete component. It has default values from database via bean.

```
<p:autoComplete id="keywords_list" 
                multiple="true" 
                var="keyword" 
                value="#{keywordsBean.keywordsListPl}" 
                itemLabel="#{keyword}" 
                itemValue="#{keyword}"
                completeMethod="#{keywordsBean.completeItem}"
                >        
</p:autoComplete>
```

I want to use JavaScript to get a list of actual values from autocomplete, change them and set new values. I use .val() to get value prom PrimeFaces components e.g. inputTextarea but here it doesn't return anything:

```
var oldVal = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('keywords_list')).val();
```

Please help.

Comment: Well to get the current selected values you may do this `PF('autocompleteWidgetVarName').hinput.val()` but I'm not sure if I would do "change them and set new values" as you said.

Comment: Thanx for comment. Unfortunately it does't work for me. 
Does hinput.val() returns a value typed by the user in autocoplete component? I need an array of selected values, because my autocomplete is multiple.
I just want to change a list of values by adding a new ones at the end. I've got an idea how to do this, but still I don't know how do I get selected values from multiple autocomplete.

Comment: To get more idea about the hinput go to the [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml), and fill some values in the Multiple autocomplete field, then in the console execute this `PrimeFaces.widgets.widget_j_idt88_themes.hinput.val()` you will get the ids not the typed, if you want the typed Strings, try this `$('.ui-autocomplete-token-label').each(function() {
 console.log($(this).text())
})`

Comment: Nice tip with this PrimeFaces.widgets.widget_j_idt88_themes.hinput.val() 
I'll use it at my project and see what is inside my widget. Thank you very much Hatem.